# Is a stationary spacetime automatically globally hyperbolic?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, vector-fields, causality

Is a [stationary spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_spacetime) automatically [globally hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold)? Can one construct a Cauchy-Surface by the existence of a global timelike Killing Vector field?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. Consider the set $\mathbb{R}\times (-1,1) \ni(t,x)$ in the Minkowski 2D spacetime equipped with the restriction of the Minkowski metric. It is ultrastatic, thus stationary, with $\partial_t$ as global timelike Killing time. However it is not globally hyperbolic because $J_+(p)\cap J_-(q)$ it is  not compact if $p$ and $q$, in the future of the former,  are sufficiently far to each other.

Comment: ok thank you! Then another question: can a stationary spacetime always be foliated by spacelike hypersurfaces?

Comment: Locally it is true, globally I do not know.

Comment: @MacMenders: *Then another question: can a stationary spacetime always be foliated by spacelike hypersurfaces?* Globally, no.